# ListView can appear in Activity but can't appear in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, kotlin

ListView can appear in `Activity` but can't appear in `Fragment` However I use the same code in Kotlin with Android Studio 3.0?

And this is my fragment code:

```
class testFrag : Fragment() {
var adapter : mo3dAdapter?=null
var listOfMkabala = ArrayList<MeetingDetails>()


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)


    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour1", "ahmed1" , "aya1"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour2", "ahmed2" , "aya2"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour3", "ahmed3" , "aya3"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour4", "ahmed4" , "aya4"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour5", "ahmed5" , "aya5"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour6", "ahmed6" , "aya6"))


    adapter = mo3dAdapter (context  ,listOfMkabala)
    tv1.adapter = adapter

}


fun test ( view: View){

}
```

this my adapter:

```
inner class mo3dAdapter: BaseAdapter {
    var  listOfMkabaln= ArrayList<MeetingDetails>()
    var context:Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context, listOfMkabaln: ArrayList<MeetingDetails>):super(){
        this.listOfMkabaln=listOfMkabaln
        this.context=context
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val mo3d =  listOfMkabaln[p0]

        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, null)
        myView.text1.text = mo3d.name1!!
        myView.text2.text = mo3d.name2!!
        myView.text3.text = mo3d.name3!!

        return myView

    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfMkabaln[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return  listOfMkabaln.size
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to mention about Android Extensions if you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a return statement after your initialization in your 
 `onCreateView()`.

You are using `kotlin-android-extensions` to get your view directly. If you use that way, you can get your `LisView` only after view created.

Your code should be like this.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
 return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour1", "ahmed1" , "aya1"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour2", "ahmed2" , "aya2"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour3", "ahmed3" , "aya3"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour4", "ahmed4" , "aya4"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour5", "ahmed5" , "aya5"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour6", "ahmed6" , "aya6"))
    adapter = mo3dAdapter (context  ,listOfMkabala)
    tv1.adapter = adapter
}
```

`onViewCreated()` runs after the View has been created. So it ensures your view already created.

You have passed the same layout for your adapter too.

In your adapter code change the  `R.layout.fragment_test` to your model layout.

```
var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, null)
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Explicit unwrapping is not necessary. Double bangs `!!` should be considered as an error.

Comment: Explain, please @Xalamadrax

Comment: it's crashed now when i open the fragment on my app

Comment: wait, let me check.@NourMedhat

Comment: Post your crash report @NourMedhat

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.agenda.nourmedhat.smartgate.agenda, PID: 3005
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: your listview is null... Can your post your complete code.

Comment: I tried your code. I found a problem, I will update my answer now

Comment: Check my updated answer. Tell me if not fixed@NourMedhat

Comment: again when i open my fragment , my app stopped.

Comment: You used the same layout for adapter too. check updated answer. @NourMedhat

Comment: The final answer make it solved , Thank you for helping :)                         var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, null)

Comment: If it is resolved mark it as correct answer. It may help others

Comment: Yes it helped me, all thing that you should do is moving adapter delcaration into **onViewCreated**

Answer (score 1):

You written code in `onCreateView` after `return` statement which we called dead code(code which is unreachable). In that manner you never set your adapter in `ListView`.

Follow 3 steps as a general approach -

1. Init all data in `onCreate` method. In your case addition of data in `ArrayList` will go there.

so that will look like -

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour1", "ahmed1" , "aya1"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour2", "ahmed2" , "aya2"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour3", "ahmed3" , "aya3"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour4", "ahmed4" , "aya4"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour5", "ahmed5" , "aya5"))
    listOfMkabala .add ( MeetingDetails(" nour6", "ahmed6" , "aya6"))
}
```

2. Only init your layout resource in `onCreateView`. Like this -

   ```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, 
                         savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

       return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
   }
   ```
3. Which is related to rendering data on UI, that should be done in `onViewCreated` method. In your case, it should like -

   ```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        adapter = mo3dAdapter (context  ,listOfMkabala)
        // Init your listview
        tv1 = view?.findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id);
        tv1.adapter = adapter
   }
   ```

Make sure you init `tv1` and it should be `ListView` reference.

Comment: i have error in this line         tv1 = (ListView)view?.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

Comment: What error? What is this tv1? Please show your imports, are you using kotlin-android-extensions for UI mapping

Comment: You are casting in Java way. Should be `view?.findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id) as ListView`

Comment: @NourMedhat Please use view?.findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id) instead of  (ListView)view?.findViewById(R.id.tv1)